# In GCP when I click on Cloud Shell to accces the console it's just displaying a white frame

Tags: shell, google-cloud-platform

Have any one have this error before in GCP? I am trying to run Cloud Shell but I'm not getting the console, it is just displaying a white frame in the bottom half of the screen as shown on picture:

[image: Empty GCP Cloud Shell console]

Comment: 1) Reboot your system. 2) Repeat the same steps in the browser. If the problem appears, press F-12 to enable the debugger and reload the page. What errors are displayed (if any)? Edit your question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is usually caused by browser extensions or various blockers (in my case it was Adblock).

The easiest way to figure out which extension causes problem is to either disable them all and then re-enable one by one or use Incognito Mode (beware that in Google Chrome some extensions might be enabled in Icognito Mode too) or in case of Google Chrome use the Guest Mode (or completely new throwaway profile).

Note that some routers with custom firmware (OpenWrt or LEDE) also might have adblocker feature that might intercept and cut traffic to certain Google servers.

Adding following exception `https://gstatic.com/cloudshell/.*` into my AdBlocker resolved the issue for me.